# Maven Release build on a project - artifact version number

Tags: maven, version, parent, maven-release-plugin, subproject

I have a maven project with the following structure

```
Project
- pom.xml
--- Module1
--- pom.xml for Module1
--- Module2
--- pom.xml for Module2
--- Module3
--- pom.xml for Module3
------- Module31
------- pom.xml for Module31
------- Module32
------- pom.xml for Module32
```

i.e. Project has it's pom.xml (packages as pom) and has modules. Each of the modules have a  `<parent> .. </parent>` section in the individual ModuleX pom.xml file where it can be either set to artifact of "Project" (which is defined in root pom.xml) -- OR it can be set to any other project2/project3/projectN artifact.

Now, due to this, I see if Project1 root pom.xml is set to 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and if I want to create a release candidate (non-snapshot) build "0.0.1", then I expect all the modules should generate  artifact with the same version which is set in Project's root pom.xml.

I noticed, that Module2 pom.xml has a parent which is some other project (for ex: Project2) and version id of this parent is set to "0.0.7-SNAPSHOT" and Module2 pom.xml (under Project) also has some of the dependencies using Project2's artifacts.

The same case exists for Module3 and Module32 where `<parent>` section has a different parent (set to ProjectN where N can be any number) and has dependencies on those or any ProjectN project's artifacts.

**My question**:
1. If I creating a 0.0.1 (non-snapshot) build of Project, then what version id artifacts Maven will generate for the root pom, for Module1, Module2, Module3 and Module31/32?
2. How can I make sure, 0.0.1 release of Project -- generates same version# 0.0.1 for all of its modules (even though the `<parent>` section of those modules uses a different project**N** and have different / newer `<version>..</version>` value set in the `<parent>` section).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html), it does exactly want you want. `release:prepare` is about verifying and updating poms, tagging the project and preparing it for the next development cycle. `release:perform` is about building the projects based on the tag and pushing the artifacts to a remote repository.

Comment: But it has some drawbacks. i.e. it creates builds twice during the release process. PS: http://labs.bsb.com/2014/02/better-maven-releases-with-jenkins/

Comment: In Maven-release-plugin link - where it says: Multi-module projects

You will be prompted for the version number for each module of the project. If you prefer that every module gets the same version as the parent POM, you can set the option autoVersionSubmodules to true. Now you will be asked only once for the release version and the next development version. !!! I'm trying to find what'd be version given to the moduleX which has it's parent as a different projectN (but this moduleX is listed in <module> section of another project, say "Project1" or "Project").

Comment: With maven-release-plugin, when I'm running mvn with -B it's giving me an error that: Can't release project due to non released dependencies maven-release-plugin. If I don't use -B (--batch-mode) option, then mvn prompts me many times+I get the desired values that Im expecting in pom files. How can I tell mvn to not prompt (-B I guess) and also make sure release version changes to 0.0.1 instead of 0.0.4 if that project's artifact has releases upto 0.0.4. This happens if your root pom aggregates module1 where module1's pom's parent section is not the root pom's artifact id.

Comment: Rob, can you please advise on my 2nd bullet question.

Comment: It looks like your project structure should be changed. Best practice is to have the multimodule be a single releasable entity. So if some modules have their own release cycle, remove them from this parent and maybe move them to another parent.

Comment: I'll try that. Any ideas, why release:prepare (if not used with -B option) prompts and sets the version values correctly to 0.0.1 when I answer the prompt and it doesn't do the same with -B (even when I pass -Dxxx for both release and next Development version) for each module in my case?

Comment: You haven't told me which version of the maven-release-plugin you are using. I've rewritten the VersionMapper in 2.4.x, there shouldn't be any difference anymore between batch and prompt.

Comment: <version>2.5</version>